# В чем может быть ошибка ввод данных Python?

Tags: python

Проблема с повторным вводом данных, при повторном подбрасывании монетки я не могу взять число меньше, т.е могу ввести, но вывод будет по результатам последнего большего числа.
К примеру если я введу число 10, то в следующий раз 8 или 5 уже программа не понимает и выдаёт результат как в случае с числом 10, а вот большее число могу ввести.

```
import random
st = 0
coin = 0
x = 0
orel = 0
reshka = 0
while True:
    st = str(input("Подбросить монетку? y - да, n - нет "))
    if st == 'n':
        break
    elif st != 'y':
        continue
    elif st == 'y':
        y = int(input("Введите количество раз подбрасывания монетки: "))
        while x < y:
            if coin == 1:
                reshka += 1
                x += 1
                coin = random.randint(0, 1)
            elif coin == 0:
                orel += 1
                x += 1
                coin = random.randint(0, 1)
        print(f"\nОрел выпал раз(а) {orel}, решка раз(а) {reshka} ")
print("Пока")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так `x` надо обнулять. Перенеси строчку `x = 0` после строчки `while x < y`. И `orel = 0`, `reshka = 0` туда же.

```
    y = int(input("Введите количество раз подбрасывания монетки: "))
    x = 0
    orel = 0
    reshka = 0
    while x < y:
```

Comment: получается-получается

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сейчас заработало